# Tumbling window 'expires' parameter less than 'size' doesn't work

Tags: python, faust

### Steps to reproduce

I'm trying to aggregate some data in the tumbling window then apply the process function to the data in the window.
I'm using the *expires*  argument to handle *late events*  (let's imagine we can get an event that belongs to the **n** minute during the first 10 seconds of the **n+1** minute).

```py
def parse_millis(ms):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ms) / 1000)


def process_window_function(window_info, values: list):
    logger.info(f"Processing window with "
                f"start = {datetime.fromtimestamp(window_info[1][0])}, "
                f"end = {datetime.fromtimestamp(window_info[1][1])}")
    logger.info(values)


class InputClass(faust.Record, coerce=True):
    id: str
    timestamp: datetime = DatetimeField(date_parser=parse_millis)
    value: int


tumbling_window_table = (
    app.Table(
        'tumbling_window_table',
        default=list,
        on_window_close=process_window_function,
    )
        .tumbling(size=60, expires=timedelta(seconds=10))
        .relative_to_field(InputClass.timestamp)
)

input_topic = app.topic("input.topic", value_type=InputClass)


@app.agent(input_topic)
async def process_input(stream):
    event: InputClass
    async for event in stream:
        logger.info(f"Event with timestamp {event.timestamp} is stored in window state")
        list_of_values = tumbling_window_table[event.id].value()
        list_of_values.append(event.value)
        tumbling_window_table[event.id] = list_of_values
```

### Expected behavior

I expect process_window_function call for **n** window only when 10 seconds of the **n+1** window will be passed to handle *late events*

### Actual behavior

The process_window_function for the window **n** will be called immediately after the first event from window **n+1** if the *expires* argument of the Table is less than the *size* argument. It looks like Faust just ignores *expires*. With such behavior  *late events* which can arrive a bit later will be skipped.

Late events will be handled properly if the expires argument is equal or greater than the size but I don't want to have a delay of more than 10 seconds.

### Kafka input

```
{"id":"sensor-1","timestamp":1614808641000,"value":1}
{"id":"sensor-1","timestamp":1614808677000,"value":2}
{"id":"sensor-1","timestamp":1614808681000,"value":3}
```

### Logs

```
[2021-03-03 21:58:07,510] [1] [INFO] [^Worker]: Ready 
[2021-03-03 21:58:41,955] [1] [INFO] Event with timestamp 2021-03-03 21:57:21 is stored in window state 
[2021-03-03 21:59:00,574] [1] [INFO] Event with timestamp 2021-03-03 21:57:57 is stored in window state 
[2021-03-03 21:59:16,963] [1] [INFO] Event with timestamp 2021-03-03 21:58:01 is stored in window state 
[2021-03-03 21:59:16,987] [1] [INFO] Processing window with start = 2021-03-03 21:57:00, end = 2021-03-03 21:57:59.900000 
[2021-03-03 21:59:16,988] [1] [INFO] [1, 2]
```

## Versions

- Python version `3.7.9`
- Faust version `faust-streaming==0.6.1`
- RocksDB version `python-rocksdb`

I had a possibility to implement such behavior in Flink but faced this issue in Faust.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It might be the same issue I had, and if so this might be the solution.
I had to set the `clean_up_interval` manually as it defaults to 30 seconds.
This property is how long before it checks for expired table data.

You can do it by setting `app.conf.table_clean_up_interval = <time as int or float>` after defining your app in the typical `app = faust.App()` way.

You can find this method in the [settings.py](https://github.com/faust-streaming/faust/blob/c1a6b0e216f62fe01f898f7dca7054bb7622161f/faust/types/settings/settings.py#L1613) file and a working example (which maybe changed recently?) [here](https://github.com/faust-streaming/faust/blob/master/examples/windowed_aggregation.py).

The only issue with this appears to be that the on_window_close doesn't appear as though it triggers correctly if the application crashes (or rebalances??) - it's like windows that expire while no worker was watching are simply gone forever and you never know about them. But I'm not yet using RocksDB, just in memory, so perhaps there's something more there you can help with?

I'm still trying to get my head around late events, as I'm using the same process to perform very long aggregations (like 3 months at 1s intervals) but i can't figure out whether data that's very old is put into a window that matches it's timestamp or just the current window. I *think* it will put it in the correct window based on the timestamp relationship to the window, but can't confirm that.